# Setting ID twice caused LinkButton's click event to only fire after two clicks

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

I had a situation where I was dynamically creating LinkButtons basically with no properties set on PageInit, and then later on adding the properties about those LinkButtons on another separate button's click event.(i.e. text, adding a click eventhandler, etc).

The problem was, I had to click the LinkButton **twice** for the click event handler to fire. Bear in mind, all of this is inside an update panel.

After looking at it up and down, I realized I was setting the ID for it to the same thing twice (on PageInit and also when I later set the properties). I saw that and figured it would muck up things in the control hierarchy and I understand it was the problem...but what I don't fully understand is the ***why***.

Can someone explain to me what the technical cause was for having to click the LinkButton twice and why setting the ID to same thing twice caused this?

**CODE**

This occurs on CreateChildControls()

```
Private Sub InitializeLinkBreadCrumbPlaceHolders()
  Dim counter As Integer = 0

  'Adding the handlers has to take place before/on Page.Init...
  For counter = 0 To LEVEL_CAP
      _linkDynamic = New LinkButton()
      'Add all the links
      Me._placeHolder.Controls.Add(_linkDynamic)
      With _linkDynamic
          AddHandler .Click, AddressOf Link_Click
          .Style.Add("display", "none")
          .ID = String.Format("lbl{0}", counter)
      End With
  Next
End Sub
```

And this occurs when a regular button is pressed (keep in mind all of this is inside an update panel)

```
Private Sub SetHyperLinkBreadCrumbValues(Optional ByVal ShouldAddAsLink As Boolean = True)

    'Don't add a new link if we went backwards
    If ShouldAddAsLink Then
        Me.Links(Me.CurrentLevel) = Me.LinkHeader
    End If

    'Go through the collection to set the values of the existing linkbuttons
    For Each element As DictionaryEntry In Me.Links
        'Links 1-based index
        With CType(Me._placeHolder.Controls.Item(CInt(element.Key) - 1), LinkButton)
            .Font.Name = "Arial"
            .Font.Size = 11
            If CInt(element.Key) > 1 Then
                .Text = String.Format(" > {0}", CStr(element.Value))
            Else
                .Text = CStr(element.Value)
            End If
            .Visible = True
            .Style.Add("display", "inline")
        End With

        Me.TrimDescriptionLink(CType(Me._placeHolder.Controls.Item(CInt(element.Key) - 1), LinkButton))
    Next
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

I have seen (and even caused) this behavior from time to time. Inevitably you are not always adding the control (or wiring up the `OnClick` event in `PageInit`. The first click causes a `PostBack` and on the second server page life cycle, you add the control during `PageInit`. On that second time around (and second button click), the event is wired up and fires the correct event. Are you possibly not wiring up the `OnClick` event every time during `PageInit` ?

Can you share some code?

Comment: I added some reference code...what you mentioned sounds logical, I perhaps might have been running into that same issue.

Comment: Why are you relying on CreateChildControls() ? Why not just PageInit?